# JAVA - Indexed or mapped properties are not supported on objects of type Map:

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

My stack trace looks like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Indexed or mapped properties are not supported on objects of type Map: get(1)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getPropertyOfMapBean(PropertyUtilsBean.java:813)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:764)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:715)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:741)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.getProperty(BeanUtils.java:382)
```

I get it here when I try to access part of a map:

```
//Property Names
for ( int i=1; i < planMonthList.size(); i++ )
{
  planTab.add("planPosition....get" + "(" + i + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't iterate over a map directly. You have to iterate over the `keySet`, the `entrySet`, or the `values` collection

**Example:**

```
Map <String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

m.put("A", 1);
m.put("B", 2);
m.put("C", 3);

// Iterate over keys
for (String key : m.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key=["+key+"], value=["+m.get(key)+"]");
}

// Iterate over values
for (Integer value : m.values()) {
    System.out.println("Value=["+value+"]");
}

// Iterate over entrySet
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : m.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key=["+entry.getKey()+"], value=["+entry.getValue()+"]");
}
```